# How to create a custom WordPress page with my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

How to create a custom WordPress page with my plugin? I would like see only a text.

Example, what I would like:

*~/wp-content/plugins/custompageforwp/custompageforwp.php*

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: CUSTOM PAGE FOR WP
 */

    // What I would like:

    if( $uri == 'custompageforwp' ) { // https://mywebsite.com/custompageforwp or custompageforwp.php
        print '<html><body>Hello world</body></html>';
    } else {}

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

function to create a page and if we want to link a template to that page

```php
if (! function_exists('create_page')) {
    function create_page($title, $template = 0){
        $a = get_page_by_title( $title, 'post' );
        if ($a == null || $a->post_status == 'trash') {
            $page = array(
               'post_type'     => 'page',
               'post_title'    => $title,
               'post_status'   => 'publish'
             );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $template);
            echo '<a style="color:green;">page '.$title.' created.</a><br>';
        } else {
            echo 'page '.$title.' already exists!<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

then can be called like this

```php
create_page('my_custom_page');
```

if there is a template to the page, we can call the function like this:

```php
create_page('my_custom_page','folder/mycustom_template');
```